# How to use C++ Struct in to C# (.net Winform)

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

Good morning. I am a beginner application programmer.

I am trying to convert a test program made up of MFC into C # Winform.

I tried to use various structures created from existing C ++ code through marshaling, but it is difficult to do marshalling because it is composed of 300 ~ 500 lines of code per structure in nested structure format.
(In fact, we do not yet have a good understanding of marshalling structures.)

Is there any way to create a C # Winform test program using a C ++ structure other than marshalling?
I am also wondering how to do this when marshalling C ++ code in the form of a very large nested structure.

If you have any, I would really appreciate it if you could upload sample sources or coding tips.

Please, Help me..... TT

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Does the C++ code have to interact with the C# code? If no, why bother? Just put your fields in a struct or class.

Comment: You _probably_ do not want to deal with C struct (no hope if you're using C++ class/struct) too much in C#. IMO easiest way is to move all your logic into a separate C++/CLI assembly (where you can use C struct directly) and expose nice managed classes you can consume from your C# UI assembly. After all this is exactly the _raison d'être_ for C++/CLI.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you even need to use C++ structures? Do you read them from some file or use them in some communication protocol or something else? Please provide a sample of where you need to do the marshalling and how your current attempt at a solution looks like.

Comment: IMO this question is NOT unclear. It's _simply_ "how can I interop with an existing C code base where structures to marshal are way too big or complex?"

Comment: *Is there any way to create a C # Winform test program using a C ++ structure other than marshalling? I am also wondering how to do this when marshalling C ++ code in the form of a very large nested structure.* You can normally have in-place marshaling (so the struct isn't copied around), but you have to know how to do it. And in the end it depends on the content of the structure.